# How to run validation on Ansible template task when using check mode?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

When running Ansible in check mode (`--check`), it seems the `validate` command is not run for `template` tasks:

```
- name: Nginx is configured
  template:
    src: nginx.conf.j2
    dest: /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    validate: /usr/local/sbin/nginx -t -c %s
  notify: Reload Nginx
```

Since Ansible is able to tell the difference between the existing destination and new file that is to be installed when running in check mode, it should be able to validate the new file. As it is now, if the template contains an error it will only show up in the real run, not in check mode.

Is there a way to validate template files in check mode?

Comment: There is an open feature request about this on https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/58688

Answer (score 2):

I think the thing you're looking for is [`check_mode: no`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/user_guide/playbooks_checkmode.html#enabling-or-disabling-check-mode-for-tasks) which has a very confusing double-negative name but effectively allows a task to opt-out of check-mode suppression.

**HOWEVER**, in your case you will want to stage that file somewhere first, so you can render the template to disk and have `nginx` test it, leaving the `mv /tmp/nginx.conf /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and its `notify:` guarded by actual check mode.

Comment: Do you know if creating a separate file as a separate task would let the verification run in check mode?

Comment: I don't exactly follow your question, but if you mean "but check mode prevents the `template:` from executing," then, yes, of course you'll have to opt the `template:` out of check mode, too, along with the "check mode now writes files to disk" risk that accompanies it

Comment: So running it in check mode would still actually write the real template to the target system in that case?

Comment: it will write it _somewhere_, yes, unless `nginx` supports checking stdin (which it _might_, if it can still find any included resources correctly); but it will only overwrite the for-real one when running in for-real mode

Comment: If I understand all this correctly, I could add two tasks (one that renders a temp file, and one that does a manual validation) and run those in check mode. Then I change the template task to a copy task that only runs if the validation task was successful? This basically feels like a manual "check mode" hack...